# Slider on map for manipulating value in QGIS 3.28.8 Firenze

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-customization

In a project, I am computing the size of the symbol for some data by using one attribute value and multiplying it by a hard-coded factor. It would be very nice to have a slider on the map (which will be published in qgiscloud) so that the user can change that value with the mouse, and when it was changed symbol sizes of all symbols using that factor are recalculated and the symbols redisplayed. An input field for a numerical value would also be ok.

So something like the transparency slider, for (numerical) values. QGSRangeSlider seems to be promising, but after some intensive search, I found no example of how to use it.

I also tried giving a not used basemap a transparency slider, and reading that value with layer_property, and making the data layer where i use that value dependant (layer properties, dependancies) from this basemap, so that opacity changes are reflected in recomputing the size of a symbol:

if ( regexp_match( "dist", 'n/a'),
20,
50 * layer_property('not-used-map', 'opacity') * "dist")

But obviously no "triggering" and recomputing sizes happens.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include statements of appreciation within your posts.